# "You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app()."

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I followed https://rnfirebase.io/#managed-workflow guide on how to install Firebase. I created a new Expo app with:

```
npx create-react-native-app -t with-dev-client
```

As written in the guide. I then did

```
npx expo install @react-native-firebase/app
npx expo install @react-native-firebase/auth
```

Having nothing in the project except a Button which, when pressed creates an account with createUserWithEmailAndPassword.

This is when I am presented with this error:

> Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().
> Ensure you have:
>
> 1. imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.
> 2. Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
>    See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.

Did I mess up on the way, or is there more steps than the guide suggests, or is the way I created the app the cause?

This was tested on an Android Emulator, launched by pressing 'a' in the terminal.

I appreciate any help!

Additional info:

I added the Google services as shown in the guide, with the name corresponding to the package name given in app.json.

Running expo prebuild --clean:

It says "(node:14360) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package" which I don't know if it could create an issue such as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the service using

```
npx expo start --dev-client
```

Meanwhile, before then, you should have created a --dev-client build using

```
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

**You will need to have an eas account if not. This will create a development build version of your project, just like the expo-go but specifically for the project will all the firebase dependencies that you have added being active. It is also the procedure for testing firebase push notification.

Fore more information, please visit:
[Create Development Build - Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/development/create-development-builds/)

Comment: Not working . this soloution i applied many times but failed .

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `@react-native-firebase/app` module and initialize, then only you can use any of the `@react-native-firebase/xxx` modules. check the official documentation for authorization module [here](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#installation).

Comment: I should've been clearer, I did install @react-native-firebase/app with npx expo install @react-native-firebase/app. I am not sure what the initialize step would be?

Comment: Have you checked expo setup for react-native-firebase in official documentation ? [link](https://rnfirebase.io/#managed-workflow)

Comment: I though so, I did everything under the "Managed" section, installing expo by npx create-react-native-app -t with-dev-client and then doing everything in successive order as they were presented.

Comment: did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

you probably forgot to update your plugins array in app.json (or app.config.js). It should look like this:

```
"plugins": [
  "@react-native-firebase/app",
  "@react-native-firebase/auth"
]
```

Then, remember that you can ONLY use @react-native-firebase/app (and other rn-firebase packages) in a dev build, so you need to execute `eas build --profile development` and then install the result in your simulator/emulator

Comment: Is there anyway we can make this work in a web app (not android or iOS)?