# Error: you attempted to use a Firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app() expo

Tags: react-native

> Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app()

I am just adding `react-native-firebase/app` in my expo project and when I start run the project, I get this error.

I have been trying many times ["You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app()."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832860/you-attempted-to-use-a-firebase-module-thats-not-installed-on-your-android-pro) with this link but it's not working is there any solution?

Comment: If you use Expo Go, this package is unsupported as it requires native linking. It would help if you used Firebase SDK instead. https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-firebase-js-sdk

Comment: In the case of Firebase native features like cloud messaging or Crashlytics are important to your app. You need to create Custom Expo Dev Client and embed pre-compile `react-native-firebase/app` in your Expo Client Build.

Comment: i am using firebase-js-sdk but same problem . problem not solved brother. Thanks for your comment. but still i am facing this problem.